# Make systemd user service depend on system target

Tags: linux, service, arch-linux, systemd

I have a user service in `~/.config/systemd/user/example.service` like so:

```
[Unit]
Description=Example service
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'host google.com > /var/tmp/example'

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

The actual service I'm trying to control actually does something useful and accesses the network, of course; this is just a simplified example.

The service is enabled via `systemctl --user enable example.service` which creates the symlink `~/.config/systemd/user/default.target.wants/example.service` pointing to `~/.config/systemd/user/example.service`.

With this setup, and with `systemd` user sessions enabled as described on the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd/User), the service is started as my user upon startup. However, it is not actually started after the network is set up; instead, it seems to start immediately, since `/var/tmp/example` contains:

```
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

(And the actual service that I'm trying to control can't reach the network either, and fails with similar name-lookup errors)

This means that the service doesn't actually run after `network.target`. How do I make it wait for `network.target` before running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget the `network.target`. `man systemd.special` says:

> ```
> network.target
>        systemd automatically adds dependencies of type After for
>        this target unit to all SysV init script service units
>        with an LSB header referring to the $network facility.
> ```

So, this target is primarily a compatibility hack for SysV init scripts.

Assuming that your network connection is handled by NetworkManager you were of course right to  depend on this target because `NetworkManager.service` defines `Before=network.target`. But this only means that NetworkManager has been started, not that the network connection is actually established. That may take a while (dhcp roundtrips, wifi handshake, etc.) and is entirely the business of NetworkManager. At least on my system (F18) there is a service called `NetworkManager-wait-online`. It uses the `nm-online` utility program to block until there is an active connection established. Try to `Require, Before` that in your Unit definition or use that tool on its own.

Comment: I'm using `dhcpcd` (`NetworkManager` is way overkill for a server, in my opinion), but either way I haven't found a way to depend on a forking executable in a service definition...

Answer (score 10):

I was having the same problem, with a userland backup script that needs access to the internet. I solved it by adding `~/.config/systemd/user/wait-for-network.service` that just pings `google.com` until it is reachable:

```
[Unit]
Description=Ping a server on the internet until it becomes reachable

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'while ! ping -c1 google.com; do sleep 1; done'
TimeoutStartSec=60s
```

Then I made my backup script depend on it like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=...
Requires=wait-for-network.service
After=wait-for-network.service
```

This works regardless of whether you use `NetworkManager` or some other means to establish the connection.